# How rewrite one url to external domain in reverse proxy configuration of apache

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

I have a configuration like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName mooo.com
ServerAlias www.mooo.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "/admin/" [PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine. Now I want to rewrite `foo.html` to some other external domain, say for example when user open `example.com/foo.html` I need to redirect to server `example.org`. For this I tried

```
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "http://example.com" [PT]
```

But that does not work. How can I make this redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below rewrite rule to proxy a page with external domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [P]
```

Comment: Why use a `RewriteCond` to check against `REQUEST_URI`, when you could just use the `RewriteRule` _pattern_?